# How to pass arguments between two spiders with scrapy callback

Tags: python, callback, scrapy

I have two scrapy that the first one crawl a sitemap and extract urls and put it in a txt file and the second one reads it and crawl this urls line by line.

my code like bellow :

```
class sitemapSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = "filmnetmapSpider"
    sitemap_urls = ['http://filmnet.ir/sitemap.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [
    ('/series/', 'parse_item')
    ]
    storage_file = 'urls.txt'

    def parse_item(self, response):
         videoid = response.url

         with open(self.storage_file, 'a') as handle:
            yield handle.writelines(videoid + '\n')
```

second spider :

```
class filmnetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = 'filmnetSpider'

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('urls.txt') as fp:
            for line in fp:
                yield Request(line.strip(), callback=self.parse_website)

    def parse_website(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        url = hxs.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()').extract()
        url = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(url))
        url = url[1]
        obj = json.loads(url)
        poster = obj['image']
        name = obj['name']
        description = obj['description']
```

How to change the code to delete read/write to the file?

How to use callback in it?

Note : This code does not work in one scrapy spider ;code is :Two given scrapy + bellow code ,As an example is said in [doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html)

```
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(filmnetSpider)
process.crawl(sitemapSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you have tried in one scrapy spider ?

Comment: thanks for your attention ,The question was reformed.

Comment: this code does not write anything inside the text file, it just extract urls from sitemap.

Comment: you said that you want to delete the read/write to the file... So the code doesn't use the file anymore and pass the url directly to the call back...

Comment: I have a question; So why did you use 'storage_file' in your code?? Does this code crawl the urls and extract requested items(like 'image' or 'name') ?

Comment: ok i forget do remove a line, i have edit the code

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
class sitemapSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = "filmnetmapSpider"
    sitemap_urls = ['http://filmnet.ir/sitemap.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [
    ('/series/', 'parse_item')
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
         videoid = response.url
         yield Request(videoid, callback=self.parse_website)

    def parse_website(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        url = hxs.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()').extract()
        url = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(url))
        url = url[1]
        obj = json.loads(url)
        poster = obj['image']
        name = obj['name']
        description = obj['description']
```

Comment: this ok for urls scrapy from sitemap (parse_item() just run) , but it dosen't return requested item in parse_website(), (this function it dosen't run)